# Как правильно развернуть фреймворк kohana3.3 с github?

Tags: kohana

скачал с github kohana3.3, но пишет что директория system пуста. и это действительно так. Все папки пустые.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Качайте либо архив из раздела [Releases](https://github.com/kohana/kohana/releases/tag/v3.3.6), либо клонируйте репозиторий с подмодулями:

```
git clone --recursive https://github.com/kohana/kohana.git
```